# Getting modern rss2email to emit reference Markdown links

Tags: markdown, hypertext, rss2email

Back in rss2email 2.70, links were emitted as Markdown reference links at the end of a post:

```
blah blah [blah blah][1] blah bleh

  [1]: http://www.example.com/blah-blah/

URL: http://www.example.com/blahs
```

However, with a modern version of rss2email (specifically in my case, 3.9), links are emitted as inline Markdown links. What's worse, they end up being word wrapped!

```
blah blah [blah blah](http://www.example.com/blah-
blah/) blah bleh

URL: http://www.example.com/blahs
```

The only relevant configuration option I've been able to find is `links-after-each-paragraph`, which is [described](https://github.com/wking/rss2email/blob/master/rss2email/config.py) as:

> Put the links after each paragraph instead of at the end.

I can't seem to find anything that controls whether links are emitted as inline or reference Markdown links.

**How can I get rss2email 3.9 to emit reference Markdown links for links in the blog post content?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This change seems to be due to changes the python3 version of `html2text`, a package used by `rss2email`. This [usage](https://github.com/Alir3z4/html2text/blob/master/docs/usage.md) for that package talks about command line option `--reference-links` doing what you want: *"Use reference links instead of inline links to create markdown"*. Looking through its python code this becomes internal config option `INLINE_LINKS` that you would need to set from `rss2email`.

Looking at the python code in `rss2email/config.py` (somewhere in your `/usr/lib/python*/site-packages/ directory or simlar)` you can see the routine `setup_html2text()` is used to configure `html2text`:

```
class Config (_configparser.ConfigParser):
    ...
    def setup_html2text(self, section='DEFAULT'):
        """Setup html2text globals to match our configuration
        """
        ...
        _html2text.BODY_WIDTH = self.getint(section, 'body-width')
```

This would be the place to add some overriding extra configuration. However, I found that either I didn't understand this code or there is a bug, as `_html2text.BODY_WIDTH` is not used, but there is a `_html2text.config.BODY_WIDTH` which seems more correct.

By editing this file and adding to this routine the following lines (indent with spaces not tabs):

```
        _html2text.config.INLINE_LINKS = False
        _html2text.config.USE_AUTOMATIC_LINKS = False
        _html2text.config.LINKS_EACH_PARAGRAPH = True
```

I obtained mail output similar to that of earlier versions of `rss2email`.